# How to get process status on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, wmi

I need to obtain the process status using VBScript or Ruby. I tried using WMI `Win32_Process` class but it seems that `Status` and `ExecutionStatus` properties are always `null`. I also tried the `wmic` command line program `wmic processes get Status, ExecutionStatus, Name`but the required properties aren't returned. On the other and, the `tasklist` command line program is able to gather those informations.

How can I obtain the process status without reverting to C# or other compiled languages?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Neither of these properties are implemented in `Win32_Process`, as you have discovered. I guess you need to work out exactly what property of the process you are trying to query. A process per se is not suspended. Threads may be. Presumably you are looking for some property of the threads of the process. What is the underlying problem that led to the question?

Comment: If your willing to use`WMIC` from your script, why not use `Tasklist`?

Comment: I need that data for descriptive purposes. If there is no better way I could use `tasklist`, but I would prefer a programmatic approach. On the other hand, analyzing the process threads could be too complex for my "development budget".